# How create a Live Agent Session by REST API

Tags: rest-api

I read documentation:

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/196/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_rest.pdf
https://piotrczechumski.wordpress.com/2014/06/22/live-agent-rest-api-documentation/

and tried to create a Live Agent Session by send this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://d.la1-c1-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId",
    headers: {
        "X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION" : 34,
        "X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY" : null
    },
    cache: false,
    response:'json',
    success: onSend
});
```

I suppose to receive parameters (clientPollTimeout, key, id),
but server return Status Code:400 Bad Request.

Comment: That would indicate to me that the URL is not correct?

Comment: "https://d.la1-c1-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/" is copy of Live Agent API endpoint. URl from documentation : "https://hostname/chat/rest/System/SessionId". As said in documentation, I replace "hostname" in this URL with API endpoint.

Comment: where you able to resolve this? I keep getting this error as well.@grimar

Comment: You will not be able to call this from JS as its creates a cross domain request and browser security will not allow you to make it work. Did you try with Datatype: "jsonp" ?

Comment: @grimar: Any resolution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

to the extent of my research, Salesforce does not allow rest call from vf page js (I May be wrong)

But the problem that you are facing is same as mine the workaround that I found is using [salesforce AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm)

Try this code this may work

```
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
   url : "https://host.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId",
   requestHeaders: {
       "Content-Type":"application/json",
       "X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION": "41",
       "X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY": "null"
      },
   method: "GET",
   onSuccess : function(response) {
          alert(response);
      },
   onFailure : function(response) {
          alert("Failed" + response)
      }
```

});

> Note: this tag is to be included

```
<script src="../../soap/ajax/41.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript">
```

> Note: this has to be run first for ajax toolkit authentication

```
sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}';
```

> Try Adding Host url to Remote site settings